# How to cause an intentional division by zero?

Tags: c++, divide-by-zero

For testing reasons I would like to cause a division by zero in my C++ code. I wrote this code:

```
int x = 9;
cout << "int x=" << x;
int y = 10/(x-9);
y += 10;
```

I see "int =9" printed on the screen, but the application doesn't crash. Is it because of some compiler optimizations (I compile with gcc)? What could be the reason?

Comment: Why don't you use `abort()` instead? Another option that can't be optimized away is writing to a NULL pointer.

Comment: @JanHudec In my case I needed specifically a division by zero. It was an embedded RT code and I wanted to reproduce system's behavior with a specific kind of failure. Things like these matter sometimes when you investigate bugs in embedded systems.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make the variables `volatile`. Reads and writes to volatile variables are considered observable:

```
volatile x = 1;
volatile y = 0;
volatile z = x / y;
```

Comment: Thus is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 14):

Because `y` is not being used, it's getting optimized away.
Try adding a `cout << y` at the end.

Alternatively, you can turn off optimization:

```
gcc -O0 file.cpp
```

Comment: Alternatively, turn off optimization :)

Comment: So, just to clarify, in my binary the line with the division just doesn't exist because the variable isn't used?

Comment: @FireAphis: if you were invoking a custom operator, and not a built-in one, chances are it would get executed nonetheless, because of possible side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

Division by zero is an undefined behavior. Not crashing is also pretty much a proper subset of the potentially infinite number of possible behaviors in the domain of undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Typically, a divide by zero will throw an exception. If it is unhandled, it will break the program, but it will not crash.

Comment: That's a Microsoft-centric view - most environments do not translate machine exceptions such as divide by zero into C++ exceptions

Comment: Nor VC++ does, IIRC on Windows divide by zero is by default a SEH exception.

Comment: It broke the program and gave me an unhandled exception when I compiled it.

Comment: @Alexander: do you mean a machine exception or a C++ exception ?

Comment: @Matteo: from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dekhbbc(VS.71).aspx : *"If the exception-declaration statement is an ellipsis (...), the catch clause handles any type of exception, including C exceptions and system- or application-generated exceptions such as memory protection, divide by zero, and floating-point violations."* This is the Microsoft-specific behaviour I was referring to.

Comment: @Alexander: typically a divide by zero will invoke undefined behavior, on some architectures it may be trapped by the hardware, the C++ standard certainly doesn't guarantee anything afaik.